# Laravel Guzzle not perforning any action as requested in Cron Job

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I am developing a web application using Laravel-5.8. Also, I am using guzzlehttp/guzzle-6.3 to consume an external api and save it in my local database.

travelupdate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\User;
use App\Activity;
use Avatar;
use Storage;
use App\Travel;



class travelsupdate extends Command {

    protected $signature = 'command:travelsupdate';

    protected $description = 'travelsupdate';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle() 
    {
        $client = new Client();

        $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.abcdef.net/travels/v4/sample');
        $trips = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);

        foreach($trips as $trip) {
            Trip::updateOrCreate([
                'trip_id' => $trip->trip_id  
            ],
            [
                'trip_number' => $trip->trip_no,
                'truck_no' => $trip->t_no, 
                'truck_reg_no' => $trip->reg_no,
                'trailer_no' => $trip->trailer_no,
                'contract_no' => $trip->contract_no,
                'contract' => $trip->contract_name,
                'driver_id' => $trip->driver_id,
                'driver_name' => $trip->driver_name,
                'loading_date' => date_format($trip->loading_date, "Y-m-d"),
                'loading_from' => $trip->loading_from
            ]);
        }              
    }
}
```

app\Console\Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\User;
use App\Activity;
use Avatar;
use Storage;
use Mail;
use App\Travel;
use App\Audit;
use Carbon\Carbon;
// use \Carbon\Carbon;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\travelsupdate',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('command:travelsupdate')
            ->hourly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        // $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that consume the external api using Guzzle GET request. Then save it into the local database. If data already exists (using trip_id), it updates. I set the cron job to every one hour.

I observe that nothing is happening, and no data is being saved to the local database. When I tested on POSTMAN, it displays the data from the api.
However, Laravel log file is not showing me any error.

How do I resolve this?

NOTE: There is no security setting on the external api.

Answer (score 2):

You are retreiving array from api and then you are using it as an object.

Solution 1: 
do not decode it as an array

```php
$trips = json_decode($res->getBody());
```

Solution 2: 
use decoded value as an array

```php
foreach($trips as $trip) {
    Trip::updateOrCreate([
        'trip_id' => $trip['trip_id']  
    ],
    [
        'trip_number' => $trip['trip_no'],
        'truck_no' => $trip['t_no'], 
        'truck_reg_no' => $trip['reg_no'],
        'trailer_no' => $trip['trailer_no'],
        'contract_no' => $trip['contract_no'],
        'contract' => $trip['contract_name'],
        'driver_id' => $trip['driver_id'],
        'driver_name' => $trip['driver_name'],
        'loading_date' => date_format($trip['loading_date'], "Y-m-d"),
        'loading_from' => $trip['loading_from']
    ]);
}
```

Everything else seems to be ok.
If you want to display errors in your log you can do it manually:

```php
try {
    ...
} catch (\Exception $e){
    \Log::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The Cron Jobs schedules still not running and no error on the Log. I'M surprised and tired.

Comment: Did you setup cron jonbs in you `app/Console/Kernel.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are misusing the terminology but you don't set the "cron job" for every hour. You set the "cron job" that calls the Laravel Scheduler to run every minute. The scheduler then decides every time it is ran what needs to be run based on how you setup the calls in the scheduler.

To test this you can adjust your scheduled command to run every minute or 5 minutes lets say and manually call the scheduler yourself, `php artisan schedule:run`, from the command line.